# window.history.back() Navigation Issue on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, cross-browser, browser-history

I am currently using a script containing `window.history.back()` on my site. While it generally works, it occasionally jumps at times, and sometimes navigates back 2 pages instead of 1. Is there a better, or more up-to-date way to implement this code? I've currently placed it inside the `<head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener("pageshow",function(event){
    var historyTraversal=event.persisted||
    (typeof window.performance!="undefined"&&
    window.performance.navigation.type===2);
    if(historyTraversal){
        window.history.back();
    }
});

</script>
```

To note, I've tried implementing `window.history.go(-1)` in place of `window.history.back()`, but received the same "jumpy" result.

Also, this is the site I am currently referencing: https://www.testblog123098.tumblr.com

The browser back functionality can be tested there live.

**UPDATE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener("load",function(event){
    var historyTraversal=event.persisted||
    (typeof window.performance!=="undefined"&&
    window.performance.navigation.type===2);
    if(historyTraversal){
        window.history.back();
    }
});

</script>
```

Changing `pageshow` to `load` did the trick for Chrome and Safari. Still encountering some snags in Firefox...

Comment: Instead of `pageshow` try using `load`. `pageshow` will fire when history has not been affected.

Comment: @StackSlave, Almost there! Your advice definitely resolved the issue on Chrome and Safari, but any idea why it's not running the same way on Firefox?

Comment: You probably just need to clear your cache.

Comment: @StackSlave, just cleared the cache, and still encountering the same issue... it's jumping back in history too far.

Comment: Re-enter the URL in your address bar and hit enter, instead of using refresh.

Comment: @StackSlave, just did, but no resolve... I am using Mac, so wondering if this could be causing the issue. I have provided a link to the site I am testing in the original post, have you been able to try that link for yourself?

Comment: There is no `event.persisted` in a `load` Event, and `window.performance.navigation` has been depreciated. You generally use `history` methods when you are using a [popstate Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate). `history` is shared across your domain. You may or may not want to `history.pushState` and `history.replaceState` to create `history` states. Navigation on your own domain also creates a `history` state. Going `history.back()` on a page you just loaded takes it to the previous domain `history` State. Probably not what you really want.

Comment: @StackSlave, thanks for the info. I am going to do some more digging into this issue, but you've definitely helped me out.

Comment: Why does the code exist in the first place? Maybe there’s a better overall approach.

Comment: @Ry-, I would like to know too... Can't understand why it works in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.

Comment: I mean why are you calling `history.back()` automatically?

Comment: @Ry-, because there was an issue navigating back with mobile browsers, due to some obscure bug with Tumblr's framework, and I had to implement something that would ensure back navigation on both mobile and desktop browsers.